# Wrapping variadic arguments in a c macro

Tags: c, generics, macros, variadic-macros

So, I want to make a function(-like macro) that takes any number of arguments of different types and does something to it.
I mean, I did manage to make it work, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution (or to make sure my way is the way it should look like).

Example code of a function macro print(...):

```c
#ifndef EVIL_PRINT_H
#define EVIL_PRINT_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define TWENTY_SECOND_ARGUMENT(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, _21, _22, ...) _22

#define COUNT_ARGUMENTS(...) TWENTY_SECOND_ARGUMENT(__VA_ARGS__, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)

#define PRINT_CHAR_EVIL(x) printf("%c", x)
#define PRINT_INT_EVIL(x) printf("%i", x)
#define PRINT_FLOAT_EVIL(x) printf("%f", x)
#define PRINT_DOUBLE_EVIL(x) printf("%d", x)
#define PRINT_PTR_EVIL(x) printf("%p", x)
#define PRINT_STR_EVIL(x) printf("%s", x)

#define PRINT_ONE_EVIL(x, ...) _Generic(x, \
            char: PRINT_CHAR_EVIL(x), \
            int: PRINT_INT_EVIL(x), \
            float: PRINT_FLOAT_EVIL(x), \
            double: PRINT_DOUBLE_EVIL(x), \
            void *: PRINT_PTR_EVIL(x), \
            char const *: PRINT_STR_EVIL(x), \
            char *: PRINT_STR_EVIL(x) \
            )
#define PRINT_TWO_EVIL(_1, _2, ...) PRINT_ONE_EVIL(_1); PRINT_ONE_EVIL(_2)
...
#define PRINT_TWENTY_ONE_EVIL(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, _21, ...) PRINT_TWENTY_EVIL(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20); PRINT_ONE_EVIL(_21)

#define print(...) do { \
    switch (COUNT_ARGUMENTS(__VA_ARGS__)) { \
        default:break; \
        case 1: \
        PRINT_ONE_EVIL(__VA_ARGS__); \
        break; case 2: \
        PRINT_TWO_EVIL(__VA_ARGS__, 2); \
... \
        break; case 21: \
        PRINT_TWENTY_ONE_EVIL(__VA_ARGS__, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21); \
    } \
    } while(0);


#endif
```

My problem with this approach is that it copies a lot of code for one call, but I don't know, maybe the compiler optimizes all unneeded branches out. Also one limitation is that it will not accept more than x (in my case - 21) number of arguments. Adding more arguments is no big deal, but the file size is going to grow, if you need like 100+ arguments.

Usage example:

```c
#include "evil_print.h"

int main(void) {
    struct {
        int i;
        char c;
    } v = {.i = 100, .c = 'A'}, o;
    o = v;
    print(v.i, ", ", o.c);
}
```

Yes, I know that it is easy in c++, don't mention that language here.

Comment: There's a reason why C++ needed to add special syntax for variadic macros -- it's not easy to do with C macros.

Comment: For the actual compiled code, use the preprocessor output to look at it. -- Anyway, what is your use case? 40+ years of C programming, and apparently millions of programmers felt no urgent need for such a construction. OK, I could use a hammer to put a screw in the wall, but is it the right tool for quality work?

Comment: I did check the preprocessor output and it was what I expected it to be (I really hope, the compiler optimizes the branches out, when the executable is compiled). Yes, sure, other people had no need for that, but it is convenient to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a more elegant solution

My most elegant solution, that I finally ended using for https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/ library, was to pass an array of function pointers that depend on the type of arguments. Such an array can be constructed inside the macro expansion with a compound literal and then passed to a dispatcher function. Because you are allowed to pass `va_list` via a pointer to the functions and then work on it, you can do type-specific operations inside the function pointers. The design is for limiting the use of preprocessor to the minimum, dispatching to function C side as early as possible.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define APPLYFOREACH_1(f,a)  f(a)
#define APPLYFOREACH_2(f,a,...)  f(a) APPLYFOREACH_1(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACH_3(f,a,...)  f(a) APPLYFOREACH_2(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACH_4(f,a,...)  f(a) APPLYFOREACH_3(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACH_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)\
        APPLYFOREACH##N
#define APPLYFOREACH(f, ...) \
        APPLYFOREACH_N(__VA_ARGS__,_4,_3,_2,_1)(f, ##__VA_ARGS__)

// ---------------------------------------------
// The main logic dispatcher.

typedef int (*lib_print_t)(va_list *va);

int lib_print_in_2(const lib_print_t *printers, va_list *va) {
    int result = 0;
    for (; *printers != NULL; ++printers) {
        const int tmp = (*printers)(va);
        if (tmp < 0) return tmp;
        result += tmp;
    }
    return result;
}

int lib_print_in(const lib_print_t *printers, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, printers);
    const int ret = lib_print_in_2(printers, &va);
    va_end(va);
    return ret;
}

// ---------------------------------------------
// Type specific printers.

int lib_print_int(va_list *va) {
    int c = va_arg(*va, int);
    return printf("%d", c);
}

int lib_print_char(va_list *va) {
    char c = va_arg(*va,
        // char is promoted to int.... or is it?
        // There are _many_ such cases to handle.
#if CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX
        unsigned int
#else
        int
#endif
    );
    return printf("%c", c);
}

int lib_print_charp(va_list *va) {
    const char *c = va_arg(*va, char *);
    return printf("%s", c);
}

int lib_print_float(va_list *va) {
    // but float _is_ promoted to double
    float c = va_arg(*va, double);
    return printf("%f", c);
}

#define DISPATCH(x) \
    _Generic((x) \
    , int: lib_print_int \
    , char: lib_print_char \
    , char*: lib_print_charp \
    , const char *: lib_print_charp \
    , float: lib_print_float \
    /* Note - comma on the end for below */ \
    ),

// ---------------------------------------------

// Calls lib_print_in with an array of function pointers
// and arguments.
#define lib_print(...) \
        lib_print_in( \
            (const lib_print_t []){ \
                APPLYFOREACH(DISPATCH, __VA_ARGS__) \
                NULL \
            }, \
            ##__VA_ARGS__ \
        )

// ---------------------------------------------

int main() {
    lib_print(1, ", ", 1.0f, (char)'\n');
}
```

The code outputs `1, 1.000000`.

> Why do you pass function pointers instead of calling them right away?

To not abuse processor, so it nicely expands to a *single* function call, accumulate the result, correctly handle error, offer additional features like format string parsing. But sure, you can just call them right away if you do not care about such stuff. You would just do plain `_Generic` with a FOREACH macro, that's all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define APPLYFOREACH_1(f,a)  f(a)
#define APPLYFOREACH_2(f,a,...)  f(a) APPLYFOREACH_1(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACH_3(f,a,...)  f(a) APPLYFOREACH_2(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACH_4(f,a,...)  f(a) APPLYFOREACH_3(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYFOREACH_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)\
        APPLYFOREACH##N
#define APPLYFOREACH(f, ...) \
        APPLYFOREACH_N(__VA_ARGS__,_4,_3,_2,_1)(f, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int lib_print_int(int c) {
    printf("%d", c);
}

void lib_print_char(char c) {
    printf("%c", c);
}

void lib_print_charp(const char *c) {
    printf("%s", c);
}

void lib_print_float(float c) {
    printf("%f", c);
}

#define lib_print_one(x) \
    _Generic((x) \
    , int: lib_print_int \
    , char: lib_print_char \
    , char*: lib_print_charp \
    , const char *: lib_print_charp \
    , float: lib_print_float \
    )(x);

#define lib_print(...)  do { \
        APPLYFOREACH(lib_print_one, __VA_ARGS__) \
    } while(0)

int main() {
    lib_print(1, ", ", 1.0f, (char)'\n');
}
```

Note: `_Generic` is meant to be used like `_Generic(x, int: functionpointers1, double: functionpointer2)(arguments, argument2)`. If you do `_Generic(x, char: printf("%c", c)` you should get a lot of compiler warnings of mismatched format string. It is easier with function pointers. In this case, you could also expand to `printf(_Generic(x, char: "%c", int: "%d"), x)`, but I still like function pointers as much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed, I don't think it can get any better. Though, why do you pass function pointers instead of calling them right away? I also looked into your library and it really is a work of art, thank you for making it.

Comment: `why do you pass function pointers instead of calling them right away?` Edited, added error handling to the `for(printers)` loop.